# Magento URLs not working after moving to new domain

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.9

Actually I moved magento 1.9 site from a domain to an other. I moved all the files and database and now site is working fine but admin url and some other urls like product, category, other pages etc.. are not working and giving 404 error. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at core_config_data for base url and admin url. Probably you will need to modify that field

Comment: I tried using this query: SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `scope`='default' AND `path`='admin/url/custom'
But it is returning empty result set.

Comment: maybe you need to update path so it matches your new url

Comment: oh I just notice while moving files from a domain to another I missed .htacccess file that was the reason. Anyway thank you